# Set name in recipients in MFMessageComposeViewController in place of mobile number

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

Hello friends I have used MFMessageComposeViewController to send message for specific mobile number. For that i have used following code:

```
if(phoneNumber)
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.body = @"Hello";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+9876543210", nil];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Here in recipients array i had set one mobile number. Can i set their name in place of the number? Due to privacy reason i don't want to show the mobile number there. 
Is it possible? If yes then how can we implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware that even if you manage to send message with a name only the user can still get the number from the messages app. There is no real way to hide the number.

Comment: No way. Hiding a number could lead to hiding a taxed number. So no.

Comment: @Larme and rockoenes i know that but i asked question for that may be someone implement like that and i don't know how to do that so.